# Return a list of Integer values that is not within a range of numbers in an existing list:

Tags: list, haskell, return, element, range

I have a list of values:

```
[0,7,4,5,3,1,4,5,5,1,7,0,7,7,0]
```

and would like to return any values that are not in the range of `[1..8]`

(i.e. I would like to return (from the above example) the elements 2, 6 and 8 in the form

```
[2,6,8]
```

)

I seem to have trouble putting this together into a function. I know that `notElem` would work well here but am not sure on how to apply the list [1..8] to the list of values shown above to get the elements shown just then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` to keep elements that satisfies a condition.

```
Prelude> filter (`notElem` theBigListOfValues) [1..8]
[2,6,8]
```

Or just take the [complement](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3a-92--92-) using the `(\\)` operator.

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> [1..8] \\ theBigListOfValues
[2,6,8]
```