# Is there a predefined haskell function that extracts elements from a list into a new list?

Tags: list, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return a list of Integer values that is not within a range of numbers in an existing list:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163640/return-a-list-of-integer-values-that-is-not-within-a-range-of-numbers-in-an-exist)

I'm looking to take the following:

```
[Vacant, Engaged, Vacant, Vacant, Engaged, Vacant, Vacant, Vacant, Vacant]
```

and return a list of only `Vacant` values from the above list.

(i.e. `[Vacant, Vacant, Vacant, Vacant, Vacant, Vacant, Vacant]`).

Is there any predefined haskell function to perform this operation?

(n.b. `Vacant` and `Engaged` are data types)

Comment: `Vacant` and `Engaged` are not data types, they are constructors of a data type.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any information other than the two different value constructors (`data Thing = Vacant | Engaged`)? Otherwise, you would be using boolean values.

Comment: @Antal S-Z it is not an exact duplicate. They were two completely different questions relating to teh same concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `filter`:

```
filter (== Vacant)
```

Alternatively, use a list comprehension:

```
[x | x <- lst, x == Vacant]
```

(Slightly longer in this case, but more convenient in some other circumstances.)

Comment: Or `[x | x@Vacant <- lst]`.